# probability that something will occur given infinite time

Tags: probability, limits

thanks in advance for the help.  Let r be a round.  Also let N be a set of coins.  Suppose that every round I flip all of the coins.  Is it correct to say given infinite rounds the probability that there will be at least one round where all N coins are heads or tails is 1?  If so how would I express this conclusion mathematically?  I believe that I could express this conclusion (as true) using a limit, but I'm not completely convinced that using a limit approach is logically correct.

Comment: Let $p_n$ be the probability that at least once in the first $n$ trials, we will have all heads or all tails. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n=1$.

Comment: I was thinking something similar, but I'm not completely convinced as to why this would imply that it would happen given infinite rounds.  Just because the limit of something is 1 (in this case probability) doesn't necessitate that the value approaching 1 will ever be 1.  For example given a set, a value may be an supremum of that set, but that doesn't mean that its a maximum.

Comment: True, this does not mean it would happen. And it might not, probability $1$ is not the same thing as certainty.

Comment: Why is probability $1$ not the same as certainty in this case? Isn't it *impossible* for there to *never* be a round with all heads or all tails, given infinitely many trials? It seems that any nonzero-probability event *must* occur eventually given indefinitely repeated trials.

Comment: I understand that in some cases, probability $1$ does not mean certainty. For example, when choosing a random real number between $0$ and $1$, the probability of getting an irrational is $1$, but it is still *possible* to get a rational like $1/3$. Is there a way we can set up the coin trials to make something similar happen in OP's situation?

Comment: "... given infinite rounds ..." I wonder if it makes a difference (to the certainty stuff that André Nicolas talked about) whether the infinity here is a countable or uncountable one.

Comment: In this case it would be countable.  Given two rounds x and y I should be able to count the number of rounds between the two.  Thus it wouldn't be uncountable

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: The analogy with random reals is close. We can define a probability measure on the set of all sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s (for technical reasons not on *all* subsets of the set of sequences). The first $N$ terms of such a sequence gives the first $N$ tosses, the next $N$ terms give the result of the next $N$ tosses, and so on. Any individual sequence has probability $0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks. I still don't understand the idea that it *might* be the case that there is never a round with all heads. Can't we be *certain* that this will eventually happen, more certain than we are of getting an irrational when choosing the random real number? I guess it's confusing that there are some cases in which probability $1$ means *absolute certainty* and some in which there are other possibilities ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a situation that considers the convergence of random variables, and so I believe the strongest statement you can make is that it converges "with probability 1" or "almost surely".

To clarify, let's define $X$ to be a random variable that represents the number of heads that turn up when you flip the $N$ coins in a single trial.  Then let's say that you repeat the experiment $k$ times and represent the number of heads in each trial by $X_i$ so that you have a sequence of independent random variables $\{X_1,X_2,...,X_k\}$. Finally, let's define $$Y_k=\min\{X_1,X_2,...,X_k\}$$
So if $Y_k=0$ we had a round that had zero heads/all tails.  We can state that $Y_k$ will converge to this result "with probability 1" if we can show that 
$$P\left(\lim_{k \to 0}Y_k=0\right)=1$$
So let's do that.

Clearly $Y_k$ is nonincreasing since it's defined as the minimum of the $X_i$'s. Furthermore, the lowest that it could conceivably be is $0$.  So let's take $\epsilon\gt0$.  Now we can get $Y_k\ge\epsilon$ if and only if $X_i\ge\epsilon$ for all $i$, which implies that
$$P(Y_k\ge\epsilon)=P(X_1\ge\epsilon,X_2\ge\epsilon,...,X_k\ge\epsilon)=\left(\sum_{j=\epsilon}^Np_X(j)\right)^k$$

where $p_X(x)$ is the PDF of the binomial distribution
$$p_X(x)={N\choose x}p^x(1-p)^{N-x}$$
$p$ being the probability of tossing a head with one of the coins.  So we know that
$$\sum_{j=0}^Np_X(j)=1$$
which means that
$$\sum_{j=\epsilon}^Np_X(j)\lt1$$
for $\epsilon$ greater than $0$.  (Note that this is a strict less than due to the definition of $p_X(x)$ and my assumption here that $p\neq0$ and $p\neq1$ since that would be trivial.)  This, in turn, implies

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}P(Y_k\ge\epsilon)\le\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\sum_{j=\epsilon}^Np_X(j)\right)^k=0$$

so that $P(Y_k\ge\epsilon)=0$ for any $\epsilon\gt0$ as $k\to \infty$.  We can then conclude that $P(Y_k\gt0)=0$ as $k\to \infty$, which implies that $P(Y_k=0)=1$ as $k\to \infty$.  So now we have that $Y_k$ converges to $0$ with probability $1$, which is to say that it converges to the result of getting all tails on one of the tosses with probability $1$.  In a virtually identical manner, the same can be said about getting all heads.

In conclusion I repeat that the strongest statement I can make about this situation is that it converges to the result you're asking about with probability 1, which actually isn't to say that it's certain to happen.  It's basically as close to certain as you can get without being certain, though.

[A bit more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables) if you're interested in convergence of random variables.

Comment: Very nice.  Similar to what we came up with in the comments of the problem formulation, but nice to see it written out.